# solution of recurrence relations of a program

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

I have a quiz which asked me to work out the solution of a recurrence relation of a program:

The amount of time,T(n) taken by an algorithm is typically a function of the size,
n, of the input data. Assume that you wrote a program that shows the following time recurrence:

> T(n) = T(n/2) + a , if n > 1
>
> T(n) = b, if n= 1

Here is what I have tried:

> T(n/2) = T(n/4) + a 
>   T(n/4) = T(n/8) + a

So:

> T(n) = T(n/4) + 2*a = T(n/8) + 3*a = T(n/K) + 3*a

Up to here, I want to make T(n) = 1 which the program should be terminated, so I make

> n/K = 1 -> K = n

And i get:

> T(n/n) + 3*a = b + 3a

However the answer shows this program have a Logarithmic complexity and the solution should be T(n) = a ∗ log2(n) + b

I do not understand how to get the above solution, can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it like this. At each iteration you halve you problem size n: from n to n/2 to n/4 and so on. You can imagine a "tree", normally you have a formula like T(n) = a * T(n/b) + f(n) then in your tree every node has degree a and the problem size at each node is divided by b. In your case the tree has half the problem size at each level but the degree of the tree nodes stays one.

```
n/2: a
     \
n/4:  a
      \
n/8:   a
       \
        ...
        \
n/n:     b + a
```

I assume you see how deep this tree is, and how to arrive at the given complexity you described as solution.

---

Another way to look at it, closer to your specific exercise: At each iteration you add an `a` right? How often do you add such an `a`?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! At each iteration, we will add one 'a', and everytime n in T(n) is divide by 2.